# Get subbounds of LatLngBounds (visible area) - google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to decompose LatLngBounds.

**How to detail the bounds of the visible area on bounds with an inscribed radius of 30 000 meters?**

Simply put, at the output we need to get a two-dimensional array (grid) with the subbounds of the main LatLngBounds.
I think that this is pure mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision:
We set the map camera inside the required area, we obtain, based on the desired radius of the inscribed circle, the parameters of one sector. Combine the upper right corner of the sector with the upper right corner of the main area. Calculate the offset of the lower-left corner of the sector relative to the upper-right corner and calculate the following in the sector row from the offset. When we reach the end of the line (the bottom left corner of the last sector has moved farther or equal to the longitude of the main area), we place on the next line a new sector whose upper right corner will coincide with the lower right corner of the first sector of the previous line. Add rows until the bottom-left corner of the last sector of the last row is less than the latitude of the lower-left corner of the main area. Good luck!